# Background-Image of Empty Result is not removed when loading question with recent activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

The Background-Image is not removed when filtering with recent activity. My first filter results in no result, displaying the Image.

After a short time the gray banner is displayed indicating recent activity on questions. Clicking the banner to load the changes, does not remove the background image and the loaded question are drawn over the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. The image is removed when loading recent activity.